Calculating fixed fields in $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphisms.
In an exercise, I am asked to determine the fixed subfield of an extension through given automorphism.
I calculated them with the $\alpha$-method, I mean, writing a generic element of the extension  using a basis for it, and them imposing conditions to it to be fixed.
The extensions were:

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ and the isomorphism given by: $\sqrt{2}\longmapsto -\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}\longmapsto\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{5}\longmapsto\sqrt{5}$. And my answer is: $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$.

$\mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})$ (with $\omega$ a cubic root of 1) and the isomorphism given by: $\omega\longmapsto \omega$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}\longmapsto \omega\sqrt[3]{2}$. And my answer was: $F=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$.


Are they right? Is there any mistake?

I am specially suspicious of the second.

$\omega$ is a complex cube root of $1$?

Yes! I am writing it know on the post
